# R code for Chow test in AR(1)

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to perform a Chow test on an AR(1), that is I would like to test whether after a certain point in time, the coefficient of the lagged term is statistically different from the rest of the time period.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
require(strucchange)
set.seed(123)
x <- arima.sim(n = 100, list(ar = 0.5))

data <- cbind(x, lx = lag(x))
sctest(x ~ lx, data = data,
       type = "Chow", point = 10)
```

Comment: Also, the chow.test() function from the {gap} package can be used to perform the Chow 1 test.